# How to format Drives in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

In Ubuntu, formatting drives is a simple process: simply select it and tell Ubuntu what you want done with it.

My question is; is there any tool as easy as that for Kubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[KDE Partition Manager](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=89595) is available in the repositories, `sudo apt-get install partitionmanager`

It is a KDE front end for libparted, the same technology behind Ubuntu's partition manager. It can be used to not just format drives, but also create, resize, and move partitions.

[image: here's some alt text]

Comment: Shame there is no 'format' option like GNOME's context menu, though :/

Comment: You need to delete and create a new partition in order for effect a format?

Comment: Does it support encryption?

Comment: This did not answer the question. The tool doesn't have a format option at all.

Comment: I love all the accepted wrong answers on this site. As @Shiv_90 noted this doesn't have a format option, period, and my mmcblk device doesn't even show up in the device list.