# How to format a SD card easily in KDE?

Tags: usb-drive, sd-card, kde4, disk-formatting

First I want to clarify that I know how to format an SD card with programs like KDE Partition Manager or GParted.

What I am really looking for is an easy way to do that, such as right-clicking in Dolphin on my SD Card or USB pendrive and selecting *format drive*.

I think I just can't figure out an easy way. Think about a way you would tell a non-sudo user how to format his SD card.

In Cinnamon, the USB pendrive can be right-clicked and formatted directly from the file manager (Nemo). Is something similar available in Dolphin?

Comment: It's not an alternative to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5245/how-to-format-drives-in-kubuntu I am looking for a easy way (1-click solution)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a one-click solution for what you want, but I think that the [USB Formatter [mintstick]](https://store.kde.org/p/1328693/) service menu for Dolphin might be close to it.

1. To add the service menu to Dolphin's right-click menu you first have to install `mintstick`. Download and install its latest version (1.4.4) in your `Downloads` directory using the following command:

   ```
   wget -O ~/Downloads/mintstick_1.4.4_all.deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintstick/mintstick_1.4.4_all.deb
   ```
2. Install it using:

   ```
   sudo apt install ~/Downloads/mintstick_1.4.4_all.deb
   ```
3. Download the USB Formatter [mintstick] `.desktop` file from [here](https://store.kde.org/p/1328693/#files-panel).
4. Supposing that you have saved the file in your `Downloads` directory, copy the file in `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus` using:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ && cp ~/Downloads/FormatUSB.desktop ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
   ```

   The above command will also create the required folders if they do not exist.
5. You should now be able to find the option to format a USB with `mintstick` (USB Stick Formatter) by <kbd>right-clicking</kbd> in a directory → *Actions* → *Format USB*.

This service menu also adds an option to also have the *Format USB* option in the device notifier, but as the author of the service menu notes:

> Note: in order to display the "Format USB" option in the removable
> device notifier, you must have pressed the "format usb" button in the
> dolphin menu at least one time.

Also have a look at the [related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLm4S_o_4vQ&feature=emb_logo) to see how the service works.

---

**Note:** I haven't tested the above, since I don't currently have an installation with KDE. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Wow, what a royal pain in the ass.